# Passing parameters to a parameter into a template

Tags: python, bottle

How do i pass the variables `filename` and `filepath` in a `static_file` statement from within a template?

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="5;URL={{ static_file( filename, root=filepath, download=True ) }}">
```

I mean i already have `{{ }}` for `static_file`, so, how to pass parameters to it?

The html template is being called as:

```
return template( 'download.html', authuser=authuser, filename=filename, filename=filename, filepath=filepath )
```

Answer (score 0):

`static_file()` is a function meant for when you want to serve a static file as a response. The file will be the only response, not some template surrounding the file content.

You just (from the manual) write something like that in
a URL mapped function, not on a template:

```
@route(’/static/<filename>’)
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root=’/path/to/your/static/files’)
```

Comment: Yes i have tried it and it works that why, but becasue i want to print a string before serving the file, like, `return pdata, static_file( filename, root=filepath, download=True )` i was thinking the html template as a middle man. Is there any way to return a string first and then the HTTP response immediately after the string?

Comment: Don't you want to return a template of your liking (with your string and such), with a link to an action that just returns the file with `static_file` instead?

Comment: How do you mean? Show me in code please what you mean please.

Comment: I do have a link to action to prompt the user to download the file, and when he clicks it the file must be returned to the users browser but i want to print some stuff first.